# jenkins - change git plugins update behavior : use pull insteade of fetch

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I am trying to incorporate jenkins with github ( using jenkins git plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin ) . But it uses the git fetch command which replaces the local changes to configuration with blank values from git server .

using git pull can fix it. Does anyone know how to change it?

Comment: Are you experiencing [this bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21001)?

Comment: @MichaelT Not exactly. i dont think this is a bug..but seems like the git behavior is hardcoded ( or i can not find any way to alter it ..yet)